# Any luck in using AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp in combination with IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm trying to get Microsoft configured as an external login provider in Identityserver4.
I succeeded by following identity server's documentation with using `AddMicrosoftAccount`:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
 {
  microsoftOptions.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
  microsoftOptions.ClientId = configuration["MicrosoftLoginProvider:ClientId"];
  microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["MicrosoftLoginProvider:ClientSecret"];
 });
```

However, I didn't have luck with getting single sign-out to work. The documentation is in line with Microsoft's documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0.

However, if you follow the instructions to create an app in Microsoft Developer Portal (portal.azure.com), the sample code on that portal suggests a different way. The sample application that the portal generated for me (WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet) is using `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp`:

```cs
 services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

Since this application is working out-of-the-box including single sign-out, Iam wondering if this is the way I have to continue.

To my surprise, however, I can't find any doc/blogs about how to integrate this approach in IdentityServer4. I almost got it to work myself, but there are a few weird issues.

Can someone clarify if using `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` is the way to go to add Microsoft as an external identity provider to Identityserver4?
Has someone succeeded in getting `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` to work with IdentityServer4?

THanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured how to get it to work.

Actually, only two things I had to do.

First, I had to remove `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` in the call to `AddAuthentication` in the example code that Microsoft generated. So the code becomes:

```cs
  services.AddAuthentication()
     .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

Then, in the code that reads the external identity from a temporary cookie, I had to use CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme. So, that code now reads as follows:

```
var authenticationResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

That was all.

Answer (score 3):

After digging around I found this statement [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/724):

**Microsoft.Identity.Web** is a simpler way to use Azure AD in ASP.NET Core web apps and web APIs.

It doesn't replace **ASP.NET Identity** in any way, it doesn't replace **AddJwtBearer** or **AddCookie** or any of the lower level primitives, but it does use and configure them correctly for Azure AD.

It doesn't work with non-Azure identity providers. It replaces AzureAD.UI and AzureADB2C.UI which are obsolete in .NET 5.0

So, the conclusion is that Microsoft.Identity.Web does not work outside Azure AD and hence not with IdentityServer.

If you do get it to work then let me know!

Comment: Thanks @Tore. However, I wonder if your conclusion is right, though. From the statement "It doesn't work with non-Azure identity providers." on the page you referred to, I understand that you cannot use the package for e.g. Google. That doesn't mean that it can't be used to configure Azure AD as an external identity provider in IdentityServer4, does it?

Comment: Doubt it will influence/help IdentityServer <-> Azure AD communication that much as that  communication is pretty established and "easy" compared to the logic it solves in the client applications.

Comment: Actually, it turns out to work like a charm with just a few changes (see my answer below). Even sign-out now works finally, as I want. Thx again for your help.

Comment: Curious, what did actually work out for you? would be nice if you could post it as an answer here :)

Comment: I added the solution already as an answer to my question. See below for the details.

Comment: Hi @ToreNestenius What should I do if I want to use the method "AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp" in the .NetCore 5? I am using .NetCore5 +React project and wanted to connect with AD B2C

Comment: Sorry, not worked with the AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp library